# Function return when tab loads firefox addon SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to make a function that loads tabs,and uses contentScriptFile to attach javascript, and emit messages to the page.

```
tabs.open({
url: "example.com",
onReady: function(tab) {
   var worker = tab.attach({ contentScriptFile: "myworker.js" });
   worker.port.emit("DoSomething", tab);


});
```

Currently, right after this code, I am using a setTimeout to wait 5 seconds, and then return.

THere has to be a better way, right? Ideally, I would like to have something in the onReady or in the function like:

```
worker.port.on("DidSomething", function() {
    console.log("did something");
   //now somehow return from my enclosing function???
});
```

And so on the "DidSomething" event, return from the function. IS there any way to do this with Promises or some other method?

Edit to clarify what the end-result might look like:

```
function addonFunction() {
var returnValue;
    tabs.open({
    url: "example.com",
    onReady: function(tab) {
   var worker = tab.attach({ contentScriptFile: "myworker.js" });
   worker.port.emit("DoSomething", tab);

   worker.port.on("DidSomething", function() {
      console.log("did something");
     //set the returnValue
     returnValue=1;
   });


    });
//WAIT HERE UNTIL returnValue is set...
 var promise = Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                setTimeout( funciton() {
                            if(returnValue == 1){
                             resolve(true);
                            } else {
                             reject(false);
                            }
               }, 5000);
 return promise;
}
```

Comment: @Noitidart any ideas?

Comment: not sure what you mean by `//now somehow return from my enclosing function???`

Comment: Hey Derek, this seems like heavy SDK stuff I would have to do some reading. There definitely is a way, setTimeout is not the way to go. Hopefully an SDK dev will put in a reply, otherwise Ill go read up a bit and try to help

Comment: *"Currently, right after this code, I am using a setTimeout to wait 5 seconds, and then return."* for what purpose? What are you trying to actually achieve? Your code example only shows your preamble, not your endgoal.

Comment: My end-goal is this: Open a tab. attach a contentScriptFile, emit a signal to the tab to kick off a function in the content script, wait on the content script to finish and emit it's signal back to this function, then return from the function

Comment: I have added some code to OP. My question is, where i have the comment "WAIT HERE"...what does that look like? I added what I am currently doing - just returning a promise that has a timeout in it to check a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest approach is to wrap the promise's constructor argument around the `tabs.open` call and then calling the `resolve`/`reject` functions inside the worker callback.

You could further break it down into smaller steps to have a promise for tab opening, one for worker creation and one for worker callback and then chain those three together.

Comment: Wow - this is exactly what I couldn't think of doing yesterday when I was writing this the first time. I ended up doing something like this - and used the timer to simply call the `reject` function if the tab script didn't return in a timely manner.